# If two cured villagers breed will the baby villager give discounts?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an artificial village with about 10 cured villagers. I have a farmer so they now are breeding. Since the newborn villagers parents are both cured villagers will the discounts carry on to the baby villager when it grows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. When you cure a villager the villager will offer massive discounts however the more you trade with it the more it reverts back to normal if you try to breed 2 cured villagers the baby will not give discounts.